# Como usar with laravel 5.6 en dos modelos y obtener sus datos

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Hola tengo una tabla llamada ReservaTabla y otra tabla llamada Canchas
Quiero obtener los datos del modelo de la cancha:

```
public function reserva(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\ReservaTable','idcanchas', 'idcanchas');
}
```

en mi Controlador tengo lo siguiente:

```
$cancha = Cancha::where('iduser', $id)->with('reserva')->get();

    foreach ($cancha as $item)
    {
        echo $item->idcanchas . ': <br>';

        foreach ($item->reserva as $re)
        {
            echo $re->start_date . '<br>';
        }

    }
```

Quiero mandarlo a la vista pero me tira el siguiente error:

> ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
>   Trying to get property of non-object

pero si le hago un dd($cancha) me sale lo siguiente:

[image: Imagen del dd($cancha)]

Comment: en que linea te sale el error?

Comment: foreach ($item->reserva as $re)
            {
                echo $re->start_date . '<br>';
            }

Comment: en esa linea me sale el error

Comment: puedes intentar lo siguiente

foreach ($item->reserva as $re) { dd($re); }

si te genera algo, puedes publicar el resultado, o si te da error también.

Comment: y si hago algo asi se rompe porque el dd no deja seguir itirando directamente.

Comment: si, correcto, lo que quiero es saber si $re si te trae algo

Comment: hay 2 opciones, la primera es que no esta trayendo la reserva y la otra es que el campo que intentas acceder esta mal. me inclino por la primera. 

Puedes pasar la estructura de tus tablas?

Comment: Prueba a llamarlo como array en lugar de objeto, es decir `$re->start_date` como esto: `$re['start_date']` ya que no es una coleccion aparentemente es un array

Comment: lo probe de esta manera:

Comment: foreach ($cancha as $item)
        {
            echo $item->idcanchas . ': <br>';

            echo $item->reserva['start_date'] . ': <br>';
            

        }

Comment: pero sigue estando mal porque cuando hace el ciclo solo me deja el ultimo elemento

Answer (score 1):

Hola no puedo comentar en tu pregunta, pero a mi me suena a que tienes mas "usuarios" y alguno(s) no tienen reservas, entonces antes de correr tu foreach de las reservas evalua si cada usuario tienen reservas con un "count"

```
$cancha = Cancha::where('iduser', $id)->with('reserva')->get();

foreach ($cancha as $item)
{
    echo $item->idcanchas . ': <br>';

    $numReservas = $item->reserva->count();

    if($numReservas > 0 )
    {
        foreach ($item->reserva as $re)
        {
            echo $re->start_date . '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```